# Two methods on computing the sum of two random variables

Tags: probability

Let $X$ be $N(0,3)$ and $Y$ be $N(0,4)$. Then we know $X+Y$ is $N(0,\sqrt{3^2+4^2})=N(0,5)$. In particular, $$P(X+Y<10)=\frac1{5\sqrt{2\pi}}\int_{-\infty}^{10}e^{-x^2/(2\cdot5^2)}dx\approx0.977.$$ On the other hand, using convolution: $$P(X+Y<10)=\int_{-\infty}^\infty f_X(x)f_Y(10-x)dx=\frac1{3\sqrt{2\pi}\cdot4\sqrt{2\pi}}\int_{-\infty}^\infty e^{-x^2/(2\cdot3^2)}e^{-(10-x)^2/(2\cdot4^2)}dx\approx0.01.$$ How come the two answers are different?

Comment: Because there is an obvious mistake in how you form and apply the convolution

Comment: what is it? it's not obvious to me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok. Define the random variable $Z=X+Y$. Its distribution function is defined as $F(Z\le z) = F(X+Y\le z)$. Using $y \le z-x$ we write this (assuming as you do that $X$ and $Y$ are independent)
$$F(Z\le z) = \int_{x=-\infty}^{\infty} \int_{y=-\infty}^{z-x}f_X(x)f_Y(y)dydx$$ 
The density function of $z$ is then 
$$f_Z(z) = \frac{d}{dz}F(Z\le z) = \frac{d}{dz}\int_{x=-\infty}^{\infty} \int_{y=-\infty}^{z-x}f_X(x)f_Y(y)dydx = \int_{x=-\infty}^{\infty} f_X(x)f_Y(z-x)dx$$ 
Then 
$$P(Z=X+Y<10) = F_Z(Z<10) = \int_{z=-\infty}^{10}f_Z(z)dz=\int_{z=-\infty}^{10}\int_{x=-\infty}^{\infty} f_X(x)f_Y(z-x)dxdz $$

Comment: I see. So the convolution is just the pdf. Thanks!

Comment: With $z$ variable, not $10$

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this is what you're looking for, but you can show that the convolution expression implies that the variance of the sum of two normally distributed random variables is the sum of the variances.  Assume that the variance of $X_1$ is $\sigma_1^2$ and $X_2$ is $\sigma_2^2$.  Then the pdf of $X_1+X_2$ is

$$\begin{align}\frac{1}{2 \pi \sigma_1 \sigma_2} \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} dx' e^{-x'^2/(2 \sigma_1^2)} e^{-(x-x')^2/(2 \sigma_2^2)}&= \frac{e^{-x^2/(2 \sigma_2^2)}}{2 \pi \sigma_1 \sigma_2} \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} dx'\, e^{-\left(\frac{1}{\sigma_1^2}+\frac{1}{\sigma_2^2}\right) x'^2}\, e^{2 x x'/(2 \sigma_2^2)} \\ &= \frac{e^{-x^2/(2 \sigma_2^2)}}{2 \pi \sigma_1 \sigma_2} \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} dx'\, e^{-\left(\frac{1}{\sigma_1^2}+\frac{1}{\sigma_2^2}\right)\left [ x'^2 + \frac{2 \sigma_1^2}{\sigma_1^2+\sigma_2^2} x x'\right ]} \\ &= \frac{e^{-x^2/(2 \sigma_2^2)}}{2 \pi \sigma_1 \sigma_2} \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} dx'\,e^{-\left(\frac{1}{\sigma_1^2}+\frac{1}{\sigma_2^2}\right)\left [ x'^2 + \frac{2 \sigma_1^2}{\sigma_1^2+\sigma_2^2} x x' + \left(\frac{\sigma_1^2}{\sigma_1^2+\sigma_2^2} \right )^2\right ]}\\ &\times e^{-\frac12 \frac{(\sigma_1^2/\sigma_2^2)}{\sigma_1^2+\sigma_2^2} x^2}\\ &=\frac{e^{-\frac{x^2}{2 (\sigma_1^2+\sigma_2^2)}}}{2 \pi \sigma_1 \sigma_2}\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} dx'\, e^{-\frac12 \left (\frac{1}{\sigma_1^2} + \frac{1}{\sigma_2^2}\right ) \left (x' + \frac{\sigma_1^2}{\sigma_1^2+\sigma_2^2} x\right )^2}\\ &= \frac{1}{\sqrt{2 \pi} \sqrt{\sigma_1^2+\sigma_2^2}}e^{-\frac{x^2}{2 (\sigma_1^2+\sigma_2^2)}}  \end{align}$$